# Android: ScrollView not behaving properly

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, android-scrollview

I have a Sliding drawer and I have put a scrollview in it. The text views contains a lot of texts. I limited the height of the sliding drawer to 100 dip but they don't seem to be scrollable. Please help.

Here's a snippet of the xml:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"
    android:handle="@+id/drawerHandle"
    android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/handlerl" 
        android:paddingBottom="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawerHandle"
            android:src="@drawable/help_tab_selector"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
        </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#B0B0B0">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helptv1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="• Hello this contains a very long text" 
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helptv2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helptv1"
            android:text="• Hello this contains a very long text" 
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/helptv3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helptv2"
            android:text="• Hello this contains a very long text" 
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </TextView>



    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Try adding matchparent, to both the attributes of the relativelayout. And also the sliding drawers width should be match parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the ContentLayout id from your inner relative view to the ScrollView to see if that assists.

Other than that, I am not quite sure. ScrollView is a trickster...

Comment: I did not quite get what you want to say. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Apologies friend, I had to pop out for a bit there. It was possibly due to it ignoring the parent ScrollView element and viewing the inner RelativeLayout element as the starting point for the SlidingDrawer element.

That is my take it on but I may be misunderstanding it. If you're still curious, play about with it a bit. Change the handle/content element to see how it plays out. I usually find purposely breaking it helps me set the boundaries of something I am not familiar with :)

Regards,
Scoch

Comment: My problem is solved. I just interchanged the IDs of RelativeLayout and ScrollView and it did the trick. Thanks to you.